# Android compass accuracy - when to calibrate?

Tags: android, augmented-reality, compass

I develop an application which provides some augmented reality features using compass. I found out that sometimes I need to calibrate my compass to make it work well.

**How do I know (programatically) that calibration is needed?**

I mean I know how to calibrate compass using the 8-pattern figure, but I want to detect that calibration is needed and display some alert to user ("Your compass is not accurate enough, please calibrate your compass sensor.").

Is this possible, please?
Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

My solution would be to use the **onAccuracyChanged()** method of the SensorEventListener interface.

This is how I would do :

```
//In SensorEventListener interface implementation    
@Override
    public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {
        switch(sensor.getType()){
            case Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD :
                switch(accuracy) {
                    case SensorManager.SENSOR_STATUS_ACCURACY_LOW :
                        doSomething();
                        break;
                    case SensorManager.SENSOR_STATUS_ACCURACY_MEDIUM :
                        doSomethingElse();
                        break;
                    case SensorManager.SENSOR_STATUS_ACCURACY_HIGH :
                        doNothing();
                        break;
                }
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
```

You should also look at this answer here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/7877688/7501326

**"Typically, if a device is not calibrated, you will see great variations in the azimuth value for small rotations. That is what I would be worried about."**